# Multiple subscribers to RabbitMQ Queue

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, publish-subscribe

I want to have multiple subscribers that receive the same messages, like fanout model of RabbitMQ.

But i do not not know if fanout model will be efficient if number of subscribers reach 10,000 or more, and there can be around 100-200 packets of data pushed in every second.

Are there any other ways I should try?

Comment: There are many factors that affect efficiency. The only way to know is to set up a proof of concept and try it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rabbitmq fanout exchanges routes a copy of message to every binded queue.
As we know rabbitmq tracks every messages states and it has a cost of performance.

May be you should consider to bring this responsibility to consumer and use another tool like Kafka.

In kafka, you may have one partition and every consumer groups can read from that partition and consumers maganes its own offsets. And you can re-consume a message for specific consumer group with just rolling back the offset.

http://cloudurable.com/images/kafka-architecture-kafka-consumer-groups.png